# Nested <span> tag inside link_to in Rails 7

Tags: nested, syntax-error, link-to, content-tag, rails7

I need the following HTML output exactly as shown below:

```
<section id='option1'>
  <a href='#option1'><h6>Option1</h6><span>&#x3e;</span></a>
  <div class='content'>Option1 content...</div>
</section>
```

I am using a Ruby block to create multiple sections like the one shown above in order to build an accordion UI.  However, the problem is that the `<span>` tag won't nest inside the `<a>` tag properly.  I have checked out other SO queries on the subject, but can't seem to find a solution.

What I hope to end up with is a Ruby block that looks something like this:

```
  <% %w[option1 option2].each do |act| %>
    <%= tag.section do %>
      <%= link_to("#{act}".capitalize, "##{act}", {class: 'centered', data: { turbo_frame:"content"}}) do %>
        <%= tag.h6 act do %>
          <%= tag.span raw "&#x3e;" %>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

But I get a `undefined method 'stringify_keys' for "option1":String`

Can someone help me construct a nested `content_tag` that puts all the required elements in the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with some fiddling with the HTML structure, I came up with the following that works:

```
<div id='accordion'>
  <% %w[option1 option2 ... optionN].each do |act| %>
    <%= tag.h2(id:"accordion_header", class: "ui-accordion-header") do %>
      <%= link_to("#{act}".capitalize, "#{act}") %>
    <% end %>
    <%= tag.div(id: "#{act}", class: "ui-accordion-content") do %>
      <%= render "/sidebars/content/#{controller_name}/#{act}", formats: :html, handlers: :erb %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
<script>
  $("#accordion").accordion();
</script>
```

I still haven't figured out how to get the anchor tags to respond to the click event and render the appropriate content via `turbo-frames` yet, so feel free to comment on how to do that.  The documentation for Turbo is (at the present) woefully inadequate.